# Calculate beta from Yahoo Finance data

Tags: excel, stock

I would like to calculate the beta of stocks to the S&P. In one sheet I have data about a stock called VNM and in another about an S&P 500 index, the SPY. I am trying to calculate the beta according to this formula:

`Beta = COVAR(VNM,SPY)/VAR(SPY)`

The code I think should work is

> =COVAR(VNM!$H$2:INDEX(VNM!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(9E+99+307,VNM!$H$2:VNM!$H$1000000)),SPY!$H$2:INDEX(SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(9E+99+307,SPY!$H$2:SPY!$H$1000000)))/VAR(SPY!$H$2:INDEX(SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(9.99E+307,SPY!$H$2:SPY!$H$1000000)))

However, this gives me an error in Excel. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to calculate the Beta of the data below is put this into the cell you want the result in:

`=COVARIANCE.S(B2:B19,C2:C19)/VAR.S(C2:C19)`

This is with Excel 2013 which gives you a choice between Sample or Population Covariance and Variance. I've done it with Sample here.

(This is just for a few days for an example, so the resulting Beta of 0.204
 will be pretty inaccurate):

**EDIT:** (Just realised the dates are messed up because I didn't format Column A correctly, but the method described is still fine as a model).

```
+----+--------------+-------+--------+
|    |      A       |   B   |   C    |
+----+--------------+-------+--------+
|  1 | DATE         | VNM   | SPY    |
|  2 | Feb 10, 2014 | 21.7  | 180.01 |
|  3 | Feb 11, 2014 | 22.05 | 181.98 |
|  4 | Feb 12, 2014 | 22.42 | 182.07 |
|  5 | Feb 13, 2014 | 22.85 | 183.01 |
|  6 | Feb 14, 2014 | 22.24 | 184.02 |
|  7 | Feb 18, 2014 | 22.55 | 184.24 |
|  8 | Feb 19, 2014 | 22.45 | 183.02 |
|  9 | Feb 3, 2014  | 20.9  | 174.17 |
| 10 | Feb 4, 2014  | 21.11 | 175.38 |
| 11 | Feb 5, 2014  | 21.22 | 175.17 |
| 12 | Feb 6, 2014  | 20.76 | 177.48 |
| 13 | Feb 7, 2014  | 20.75 | 179.68 |
| 14 | Jan 24, 2014 | 20.35 | 178.89 |
| 15 | Jan 27, 2014 | 20.53 | 178.01 |
| 16 | Jan 28, 2014 | 20.91 | 179.07 |
| 17 | Jan 29, 2014 | 20.76 | 177.35 |
| 18 | Jan 30, 2014 | 21.31 | 179.23 |
| 19 | Jan 31, 2014 | 21.07 | 178.18 |
+----+--------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: @pnuts Maybe, but I'm not sure that the OP was aware that `COVARIANCE` and `VARIANCE` acted element-wise on the arrays selected.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t comment on your choice of functions but with them there seems nothing wrong with your syntax, though a slightly shorter version seems adequate, here split into its components:

```
=COVAR(VNM!$H$2:INDEX(VNM!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(1E+100,VNM!$H$2:$H$1000000)),
       SPY!$H$2:INDEX(SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(1E+100,SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000))
      )
/
   VAR(SPY!$H$2:INDEX(SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000,MATCH(1E+100,SPY!$H$2:$H$1000000)))
```

The error seem likely either `#DIV/0!` if either of the arrays is empty (mischoice of column reference perhaps?) or `#N/A`, which can be caused by [different number of data points](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/covar-HP005209036.aspx) in the two series. Since the formula determines the series as from Row2 to the last occupied cell in ColumnH in each case I suggest checking that the bottom of each list is in the same row number for each, perhaps with Home > Editing – Find & Select, Go To Special…, Last Cell (depending upon what else is in each sheet however).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem, that the series had a different amount of entries. I now calculated beta over the last year.

Answer (score -1):

```
|  0 | DATE         | VNM   | SPY    |          
|  1 | Feb 19, 2014 | 22.45 | 183.02 |          
|  2 | Feb 18, 2014 | 22.55 | 184.24 |          
|  3 | Feb 14, 2014 | 22.24 | 184.02 |          
|  4 | Feb 13, 2014 | 22.85 | 183.01 |          
|  5 | Feb 12, 2014 | 22.42 | 182.07 |          
|  6 | Feb 11, 2014 | 22.05 | 181.98 |          
|  7 | Feb 10, 2014 | 21.7  | 180.01 |          
| 08 | Feb 7, 2014  | 20.75 | 179.68 |          
| 09 | Feb 6, 2014  | 20.76 | 177.48 |          
| 10 | Feb 5, 2014  | 21.22 | 175.17 |          
| 11 | Feb 4, 2014  | 21.11 | 175.38 |          
| 12 | Feb 3, 2014  | 20.9  | 174.17 |          
| 13 | Jan 31, 2014 | 21.07 | 178.18 |          
| 14 | Jan 30, 2014 | 21.31 | 179.23 |          
| 15 | Jan 29, 2014 | 20.76 | 177.35 |          
| 16 | Jan 28, 2014 | 20.91 | 179.07 |          
| 17 | Jan 27, 2014 | 20.53 | 178.01 |          
| 18 | Jan 24, 2014 | 20.35 | 178.89 |          


VNM     SPY    RETURN SPY   RETURN VNM
               (X-axis)     (Y-axis)
22.45   183.02  -0.00662    -0.00443
22.55   184.24  0.001196    0.013939
22.24   184.02  0.005519    -0.0267
22.85   183.01  0.005163    0.019179
22.42   182.07  0.000495    0.01678
22.05   181.98  0.010944    0.016129
21.7    180.01  0.001837    0.045783
20.75   179.68  0.012396    -0.00048
20.76   177.48  0.013187    -0.02168
21.22   175.17  -0.0012     0.005211
21.11   175.38  0.006947    0.010048
20.9    174.17  -0.02251    -0.00807
21.07   178.18  -0.00586    -0.01126
21.31   179.23  0.010601    0.026493
20.76   177.35  -0.00961    -0.00717
20.91   179.07  0.005955    0.018509
20.53   178.01  -0.00492    0.008845
20.35   178.89  #DIV/0!     #DIV/0
```

Beta = `=slope(y's axis data, x's axis data)` ...Use function from Excel `=slope(`

```
 = 0.4088
```